# HTTP language representation

Tags: http, rest, web

In the HTTP language, the following lines expresses a GET request on a collection of articles:

```
GET /articles HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json; level=1
Host: example.com
```

However, in this language, how can we express a request through a POST with its data? Is there an official spec? Thank you.

**Edit**

Using `curl`, a such request could be:

```
curl  -H 'Accept: application/json; level=1' \
      -X POST \
      -d '<json>' \
      http://example.com/articles
```

...where `<json>` could be:

```
{
  "article": {
    "title": "foo"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example can be a `POST` with an empty body since your request is composed only of HTTP headers.  But I don't recommend this.
You can read about HTTP in the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)

Comment: Assuming there is data, how can we write the query? From the RFC, this information is not provided.

Comment: @Zagzag..:What do you mean?The data are part of the body